# Force vncserver started by lightdm to localhost on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: localhost, ubuntu-14.04, vncserver

I am using vncserver with lightdm on ubuntu 14.04  on an amazon EC2 instance. I created a lightdm.conf:

```
#
# VNC Server configuration
#
# enabled = True if VNC connections should be allowed
# port = TCP/IP port to listen for connections on
#
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
port=5901
width=1024
height=768
depth=8
```

However the vncserver is started to listen on any ip:

```
netstat -atn:

...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
...
```

I can start the vncserver manually with the `-localhost` flag.

How do I tell lightdm or vncserver to listen only to locahost?

Comment: This is not currently possible. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1390808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [November 2014](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/lightdm/blame/95e48f409295bc3ff9dbf3d1affd0fcd7a6d1698/data/lightdm.conf#L151) or [December 2015](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1390808/comments/11) (depending on perspective), LightDM has added the `listen-address` configuration option to the `[VNCServer]` section.

So the section in your `lightdm.conf` (or the file in `lightdm.conf.d`) would change to:

```
#
# VNC Server configuration
#
# enabled = True if VNC connections should be allowed
# command = Command to run Xvnc server with
# port = TCP/IP port to listen for connections on
# listen-address = Host/address to listen for VNC connections (use all addresses if not present)
# width = Width of display to use
# height = Height of display to use
# depth = Color depth of display to use
#
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
port=5901
listen-address=localhost
width=1024
height=768
depth=8
```